# Should I delete all these Python frameworks? (cross-post from Ask Different where nobody is answering)

Tags: macos, python, homebrew

I'm just getting started with web development and I'm trying to set up my environment, and I can't do that until Dr Homebrew has discharged me from N00bcake Hospital. This is what I'm getting:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

I'm worried because [I already have a working installation of Python](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97561/how-to-update-python-on-a-mac-with-unix-commands) which is a good enough algorithm playground, and I don't want to leave my framework worse than it was before, but I reckon I should do what Homebrew says if I want to continue. Should I just run `$ rm -f /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and call it a day or is there something else I must do? `$ python --version && python3 --version` returns

```
Python 2.7.6
Python 3.3.2
```

and `$ brew --config` returns

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: 1304a2b29a3de5da2b31e1656bf772eea2a78dc1
Last commit: 5 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: dual-core 64-bit core2
OS X: 10.6.8-i386
Xcode: 4.2
CLT: N/A
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 3.0 build 211
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-p249
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.6.0_65
```

which brings up another odd thing: I was certain my processor was a 32 bit Intel Core Duo and that's why I couldn't update my OS, but this says `dual-core 64-bit core2`. What is going on?

**TL;DR** do I delete `/Library/Python.framework` or not

Comment: Please don't crosspost . Instead read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I crossposted as a last resort because I know the standard course of action when nobody's answering a question and it wasn't getting me any good results.

Comment: You only waited 9 hours before crossposting ... :/

Comment: And I frequently get answers fifteen minutes after I post a topic. If everyone has to wait two days on a site with a large userbase so that a question is eligible for bounty just to _get help on something_, even after writing a detailed and specific question, it's gonna be hard for people to learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by moving "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework" to another location and see if it causes anything to break (presumably not). If you can't find anything depending on it, you can safely remove it, as it is not normally part of OS X.

EDIT:
After moving it, you should try to reinstall it through Brew